# Content-Type JSON SIGABRT Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsurlrequest

I am trying to parse JSON, and getting a SIGABRT Error: `reason: '[<NSURLRequest 0x7e7e970> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Content-Type.`

My code is:

```
self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                         [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dmsfw01.dev.com:8082/G.FQI/GVOLFQI.svc/Search(v)?Start=1&Count=10"]];

NSString *contentType = @"application/json";
[request setValue:contentType forKey:@"Content-Type"];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

What should I do instead to set the Content-Type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error because you are using a [Key Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method that tries to set a property on request with the name `Content-Type`. Also you can not modify an `NSURLRequest` because it is immutable. Use an [`NSMutableURLRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead and then call `- (void)setValue:(NSString *)value forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)field`.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sw730voldmsfw01.vol1dev.com:8082/GVOL.FQI/GVOLFQI.svc/Search(visa)?Start=1&Count=10"]];

NSString *contentType = @"application/json";
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Comment: ...and also, use the `setValue:forHTTPHeaderField` method, not `setValue:forKey`